# Looking for a guide on using exposing inserts via odata

Tags: c#, wcf, odata

I'm having trouble finding a guide on how to expose an insert Post method via odata (wcf). I currently have an entity set exposed and I want to be able to verfiy the input before a new entity is inserted into the database. I dont just want to expose an operation if possible but have the `get` return an entity set and `post` insert that entity set with the same endpoint.

Can anyone link me to one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your question but I have a feeling you are looking for [interceptors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744842.aspx) - especially for `ChangeInterceptor` (in case of WCF Data Services).

Answer (score 0):

As part of the WCF Data Service infrastructure you have what is known as Interceptors. These help you to grab the request that came in and work on that before it reaches the code which fetches the data or inserts the data. With interception you can do a custom logic that you want to do and go ahead and revert back to the client. So look out for interceptors concept.